# Backbone.js Hiding path in console of web browser

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm not sure whether require.js problem or not. Currently I'm coding using backbone.js, underscore.js, require.js and !text plugin.

Whenever I browser each router then my console is show all the path or link that I request from my project and web service :

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require js is certainly not a problem. Even i am using all of these frameworks and it shows all this info in 'Networks' tab only which is not possible to hide.
Are you getting these urls under 'console' tab?

Comment: I am sure you are using Firefox. Under 'console' tab, there is 'Net' option. Under that you need to uncheck 'log'. That will do your job.

Comment: OMG! I never think it was because of Firefox. Actually uncheck on `Show XMLHttpRequests` under Console tab. Thanks for pointing that out.